# Database script to update the url port

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

I have database table like

```
Attachement
URL VARCHAR(300),
USER VARCHAR(100),
NAME VARCHAR (1000)
```

URL has information like

`http://xample1.test.com:8081/test`,
 `http://example1.test.com:8081/test2`.

I want to write a script update
 the port of this URL 
to

`http://xample1.test.com:8083/test`,
`http://xample1.test.com:8083/test2`.

The database contains millions of records, Hence `Update` query needs to be performent.
                                           Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention your RDBMS.

In MySQL it would be:

```
UPDATE Attachement
SET URL = REPLACE(URL, ':8081/', ':8083/')
```

Decide for yourself how safe this is. You might want to have a backup.

> The databse contains millions of records, Hence update query needs to be performent.

It takes as long as it takes, since you have to look up every row anyway, there's actually no room for improvement.

Comment: It can also be used in oracle10g the same way